# NodeJS - Generate PDF/A compliant document

Tags: node.js, angular, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfa

#### Current Setup

I have an Angular app that takes in user inputs and passes that data to a NodeJS service which then generates a PDF. I'm currently making use of the [`pdfmake`](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) package.

#### Requirement

The above package doesn't create a PDF/A document. Therefore, I wanted to know if there are any existing or upcoming NodeJS packages that generates a PDF/A compliant document.

Or is there any other way that I can produce a PDF/A document (by converting the generated `pdf` to `pdf/a`?).

Comment: Do you know which variant of PDF/A you need to target? e.g PDF/A-1A or PDF/A-2B?

Comment: @Ryan - No specific requirement. Any would do to be honest.

Comment: For automated conversion to PDF/A, PDF/A-2B is a great choice. Balancing modern PDF features not available in PDF/A-1 and B has less requirements than A. See here for more info: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pdfnet-sdk/IlHHJpIfkaw/CyYPjHXYCQAJ

Comment: Did someone found a solution which uses a free lib?

Answer (score 1):

[PDFTron SDK](http://www.pdftron.com/) can be used to automatically convert many PDF files to PDF/A. If it cannot convert you would at least get a full report of any issues. But since you are creating the PDF files that should not be a problem, and you should be able to convert to PDF/A.

This can be done client side or server side, depending on what best meets your needs.

- Client Side: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/samples/pdfnetjs-full#pdfa
- Server Side: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples?platforms=linux#PDF/A
- CLI: See PDF/A Manager here https://www.pdftron.com/downloads/linux

Comment: Cheers @Ryan, but this seems to be available for Java, Ruby or PHP but not NodeJS which I was looking out for.

Comment: The "client side" link above was for the javascript version of our SDK, PDFNetJS. You can just load that server side in your nodejs javascript. It is definitely compatible with NodeJS. Feel free to contact support and we can assist you further with integrating.

Comment: Is there a free lib to do so?