# Nodejs library for creating/converting PDF/A

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, pdf

Trying to find some library able to convert / create a PDF/A (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A)

The already present anwers about it seems to call an external service ([NodeJS - Generate PDF/A compliant document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266392/nodejs-generate-pdf-a-compliant-document)) or no response at all ([How to create pdf/a-1b file using node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570586/how-to-create-pdf-a-1b-file-using-node-js))

I know that some libs exist on other languages (ghostscriptProcessor), but i cannot find anything on npmjs.com

Answer (score -1):

I recently found [PDFme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pdfme/generator) library. This library is open source and is base on [PDF-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib). It runs on Node and browser and creates a 1.7 version of the PDF, in your case probably PDF/A-2.